# Differential Geometry- does there exist not identity rigid motion that $f \circ \gamma $ is a reparametrization of $\gamma$

Tags: differential-geometry

Does there exist a regular curve $\gamma : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^{3}$ and a rigid motion $f$ so that $f$ is not identity motion and $f \circ \gamma $  is a reparametrization of $\gamma$?

Definition of regular curve $\gamma : I\to \mathbb{R}$ smooth, then $|\gamma'(t) | \neq 0$, $\forall t \in I$.

By definition of rigid motion, function $f:\mathbb{R}^{n} \to \mathbb{R}^{n}$ that preserves distance.

I tried to do by definitions but could not find true way.

Comment: What if $\gamma$ is a line?

Comment: Or a circle or a helix .....

Answer (score 1):

Sure, take $\gamma(t) = (t,t,t)$ and $f = -{\rm Id}$. Then $f(\gamma(t)) = (-t,-t,-t) = \gamma(-t)$, and $\gamma$ is regular.

Comment: Can we show this by using that $f=T_{q}\circ L_{A}$  where A is orthogonal 3x3 matrix and $q\in \mathbb{R}^{3}$, $T_{q}$ is translation map and $L_{A}$ is linear transformation.